# How to display multiple images from Custom Fields in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

I have a custom field called "images". I would like to show this custom field as a picture. How can I do that?

https://prnt.sc/l0eyv3

I've written a php code, but it shows only 1 image, it doesn't show any other images.

my code:

```
<?php $images = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'images', true); ?>
<?php if ( $images && is_single() ): ?>
<?php
    $images = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'images' );
    if ( $images ) {
        foreach ( $images as $attachment_id ) {
            $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, 'full' );
            $full_size = wp_get_attachment_url($attachment_id);
            printf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', $full_size, $thumb );
        }
    }
?></br>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Are you using CPT or another plugin for the custom fields? Just wondering if 'images' is an image field, or a string you're filling out yourself.

Comment: Nevermind, just saw your image. one sec.

Comment: @KingRichard I'm using the WP User Frontend add-on for custom fields. When the user adds a images from frontend, I want to show it in the posts.

Comment: I just updated my answer, just in case you're trying to use it already. Move the explode statement inside the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. See comment for explanation.

```
<?php
$images = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'images', true);
if ( $images && is_single() ):
    $images = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'images' );

    if ( $images ) {
        //you can't loop through strings, you need to convert the string to an array
        $images = explode( ",", $images );

        foreach ( $images as $attachment_id ) {
            $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image( intval($attachment_id), 'full' );
            $full_size = wp_get_attachment_url($attachment_id);
            printf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', $full_size, $thumb );
        }
    }
    echo '<br>';
endif;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work. Currently showing 1 images. The remaining 2 images are not displayed.